# How to Manually Combine the code of 4 Responsive stylesheets into One stylesheet

Tags: css, responsive-design

I Just created a Responsive home web page with 4 responsive stylesheets. I just want to **"Manually" Combine the code of all 4 stylesheets into One stylesheet.** Please tell how to do it.

Comment: Copy and paste them all into the same file. Done.

Comment: Literally append the contents of one file to another...

Comment: But What about the Media Queries, which Call the large_layout.css medium_layout.css & small_layout.css.

Comment: just make sure you have your new file in the same order as your four separate files and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use YUI compressor to minify them and have them all into a single stream that you can paste in a single file. You can do this manually, or have a simple script that you run when you deploy.

You can try if it works for you [online.](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/)

Comment: please suggest a Manual way that How to Combine / merge the code of all 4 css files i.e. (1) styles.css (2) large_layout.css (3) medium_layout.css & (4) small_layout.css Into a Single css file. In which Css file & In which Order, I should copy & paste the code of all three files.

Comment: Go to the link I gave you, choose your files from your computer and the tool will give you the result you need.

Comment: thanks @palako, Combining is done. But when I Link the Single Combined Css file in the html, mess happened to the layout.

Comment: you can use firebug or the webkit web developer tools in chrome or safari to debug what's wrong.

Comment: Actually the issue is that (the code of all 4 above mentioned responsive stylesheets is not working ""with a Single stylesheet""). As a result following happen: -
(1) The responsiveness of web page  is gone.
(2) Everything in webpage is cluttered.